# AES: Searching for a key given the decrypted text and the encrypted text

Tags: php, encryption, aes

Although this may sound impractical, please hear me out...

Let's say I have two strings: 

"test"
"apis"

I want to use AES 256-bit Encryption to convert the first string to the second string.

In AES (or any similar) Encryption, is it possible to search for a key that would work for such a situation, where the decrypted and encrypted text are known but not the passphrase?

If so, could someone suggest how I could implement it in PHP?

Comment: I do not believe this is possible, no. And even if it were, I would  be suspicious of your motives. If you are supposed to hold the key, you already would, right?

Comment: AES blocksize is minimun 128 bits, so "apis" is an impossible ciphertext.

Comment: @Qwerky That depends on the mode of operation more than the block cipher. If you use AES-CTR you can - in principle - encrypt each bit separately (as long as you don't reuse the key). There is also format preserving encryption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how bruteforcing encryption works, well the other way around, but still. You try all possible combinations and see if the decrypted text makes sense.

Unless the encryption algorithm is completely broken, you can't do what you ask. AES-256 is not broken.

Imagine if this was possible, then you could find the encryption key in a https dialog for instance as a response always starts the same way. I.e. `"200 Ok"`

Comment: Thank you, that clarified things for me. I didn't think of what I was doing as bruteforcing but that is exactly what it is.